# Query has some issues

Tags: asp.net, oracle

When I m writing this query in the code on button click to insert the `mkey` in the `xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h` table
it gives me error as

> "ORA-00904: "A": invalid identifier"

Here is my code:-

```
try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part where mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();  // this query gives error
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=convert(datetime,'" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "',103) WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Broker rating updated succesfully');", true);

    }
```

I am using Oracle

**UPDATE**

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString);
    string strQuery = "SELECT distinct ab.mkey, ab.broker_id,CASE WHEN SYSDATE - la.creation_date <= 180 THEN 'A' WHEN SYSDATE - cef_dt <= 30 THEN " +
                       "'B' ELSE 'C'END rating FROM xxacl_pn_new_cha_part ab,xxacl_pn_lease_det ld,xxacl_pn_leases_all la, " +
                       "xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v ce WHERE ab.broker_id = ld.broker_id(+) AND ld.booking_no = la.booking_no(+) " +
                       " AND ab.broker_id = ce.broker_id(+)";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=convert(datetime,'" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "',103) WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Broker rating updated succesfully');", true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better to write column names instead of *\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the alias name here, try this one

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();
```

UPDATE:

```
 protected void btnUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OracleConn"].ConnectionString);
    string strQuery = "SELECT distinct ab.mkey, ab.broker_id,CASE WHEN SYSDATE - la.creation_date <= 180 THEN 'A' WHEN SYSDATE - cef_dt <= 30 THEN " +
                       "'B' ELSE 'C'END rating FROM xxacl_pn_new_cha_part ab,xxacl_pn_lease_det ld,xxacl_pn_leases_all la, " +
                       "xxcus.xxacl_pn_customer_enquiry_v ce WHERE ab.broker_id = ld.broker_id(+) AND ld.booking_no = la.booking_no(+) " +
                       " AND ab.broker_id = ce.broker_id(+)";

    OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        OracleDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (sdr.Read())
        {
            cmd.CommandText = "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select 0, sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss am') WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();
            cmd.CommandText = strQuery;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", "alert('Broker rating updated succesfully');", true);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: now getting error as `ORA-00947: not enough values`

Comment: It means the number of columns in `xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h` is more than the number of columns returned from `select sysdate, a.*`. Check the query again.

Comment: @nadeem check no of column present in two tables xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h and xxacl_pn_new_cha_part and also check the columns data types also.

Comment: Can you list the columns from both the tables? xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h and xxacl_pn_new_cha_part. If the former has 6 columns and the later has 5 columns, sysdate together with 5 columns will form 6 columns, but if there are less than 5 columns in xxacl_pn_new_cha_part, you will never have all the 6 columns.

Comment: After adding 0 and sysdate then query will be "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select sysdate, a.* , 0 , sysdate from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();

Comment: It would be lot easier for us if you could list the column names of both the tables here.

Comment: OK, here it goes `cmd.CommandText = "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select 0, sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();`

Comment: Which data base is this? Is it Oracle or SQL Server?

Comment: Its oracle, and I want to show **Time** also along with date

Comment: Convert is used in SQL Server, use this `strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','dd/mm/yyyy') WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();`

Comment: still error as `ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string`

Comment: What value is returned by `DateTime.Now.ToString()`. The data format will depend on the value returned from this string. For now I have used 'dd/mm/yyyy', modify the format to suit your requirement. More on format [here](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php)

Comment: This should work `strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss am') WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();`

Comment: This should work `strQuery = "UPDATE xxacl_pn_new_cha_part set Rating='" + sdr[2].ToString() + "', RATING_UPDATE_DATE=to_date('" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + "','dd-mm-yyyy hh:mi:ss am') WHERE mkey = " + sdr[0].ToString();`

Comment: Get a sequence created in the Oracle database and instead of using `0` in the query, use `select <sequence_name>.nextval, sysdate, a.*`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89644/discussion-between-nadeem-and-san).

Comment: @San, I did it myself. Please update your answer so that I can mark it correct.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the alias name of a table

```
 "insert into xxacl_pn_new_cha_part_h select sysdate, a.* from xxacl_pn_new_cha_part a where a.mkey= " + sdr[0].ToString();
```